# Is there a way to use a SVG gradient as input to a displacement map?

Tags: javascript, svg, svg-filters

I'm trying to generate a gradient that I could use as a feDisplacementMap to distort text in SVG. How do I need to set it?

I've tried creating it as part of the SVG, and hiding the gradient, but am unable to make it work this way.

```html
  <svg
          filter="url(#f)"
          overflow="auto"
          viewBox="0,0,200vw,200vh"
          width="100%"
          height="100vh"
        >
          <defs>
            <radialGradient id="rg" r=".9">
              <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#f00"></stop>
              <stop offset="10%" stop-color="#000"></stop>
              <stop offset="20%" stop-color="#f00"></stop>
              <stop offset="30%" stop-color="#000"></stop>
              <stop offset="40%" stop-color="#f00"></stop>
              <stop offset="50%" stop-color="#000"></stop>
              <stop offset="60%" stop-color="#f00"></stop>
              <stop offset="70%" stop-color="#000"></stop>
              <stop offset="80%" stop-color="#f00"></stop>
              <stop offset="90%" stop-color="#000"></stop>
              <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#f00"></stop>
            </radialGradient>
    
            <filter id="f" primitiveUnits="objectBoundingBox">
              <feImage result="pict2" xlink:href="#witness"></feImage>
              <feDisplacementMap
                scale=".05"
                xChannelSelector="R"
                yChannelSelector="R"
                in2="pict2"
                in="SourceGraphic"
              ></feDisplacementMap>
            </filter>
    
            <pattern id="imageFill" width="1" height="1" viewBox="0 0 300 300">
              <image id="ripples" width="300" height="300" xlink:href="" />
            </pattern>
          </defs>
          <text height="100vh" text-anchor="middle" class="svgText">
            <tspan height="100vh" x="50%" y="50%">text</tspan>
          </text>
          <rect
            id="witness"
            width="100%"
            height="100%"
            stroke="none"
            opacity="0"
            fill="url(#rg)"
          />
        </svg>
```

I would like to be able to distort the text with the generated gradient while keeping it hidden. Thanks so much for your time and help :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Radial gradients applied to text.

```css
.container {
width:100%;
height:100%;
}
#txt1 {
font-size: 200px;
font-weight:bold;
font-family: 'Signika', sans-serif;
fill:url(#rg);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<svg viewBox="0 0 750 300"    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  
xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
                   
    <defs>
      <radialGradient id="rg" r=".9">
              <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#f00"></stop>
              <stop offset="10%" stop-color="#000"></stop>
              <stop offset="20%" stop-color="#f00"></stop>
              <stop offset="30%" stop-color="#000"></stop>
              <stop offset="40%" stop-color="#f00"></stop>
              <stop offset="50%" stop-color="#000"></stop>
              <stop offset="60%" stop-color="#f00"></stop>
              <stop offset="70%" stop-color="#000"></stop>
              <stop offset="80%" stop-color="#f00"></stop>
              <stop offset="90%" stop-color="#000"></stop>
              <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#f00"></stop>
            </radialGradient>
    </defs>
    <text id="txt1" x="15%" y="75%"  >Stack</text>
  </svg>
  </div>
```

- Add filters `feTurbulence` and`feDisplacementMap`

By changing the values of the `baseFrequency` and`scale` filter attributes you can get interesting effects

Below is an example of a text distortion animation with gradients:

The animation starts when you hover  the text `begin =" txt1.mouseover "`

the animation ends - `end =" txt1.mouseout "`, or at the end of the animation time - `dur =" 18s "`

```css
#txt1 {
font-size: 200px;
font-weight:bold;
font-family: 'Signika', sans-serif;
fill:url(#rg);
filter:url(#myFilter);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<svg  width="750" height="300" version="1.1"
viewBox="0 0 750 300"    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
                   
    <defs>
       <radialGradient id="rg" r=".9">
              <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#f00"></stop>
              <stop offset="10%" stop-color="#000"></stop>
              <stop offset="20%" stop-color="#f00"></stop>
              <stop offset="30%" stop-color="#000"></stop>
              <stop offset="40%" stop-color="#f00"></stop>
              <stop offset="50%" stop-color="#000"></stop>
              <stop offset="60%" stop-color="#f00"></stop>
              <stop offset="70%" stop-color="#000"></stop>
              <stop offset="80%" stop-color="#f00"></stop>
              <stop offset="90%" stop-color="#000"></stop>
              <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#f00"></stop>
            </radialGradient>
    <filter id="myFilter" >
         <feTurbulence type="turbulence" baseFrequency="0.0001" numOctaves="1" result="turbulence" >
          <animate attributeName="baseFrequency"
      dur="18s"
   values="0.0001;0.02;0.0001;0.02;0.0001"
   begin="txt1.mouseover"
   end="txt1.mouseout" />
      </feTurbulence>
    <feDisplacementMap xChannelSelector="R" yChannelSelector="G" scale="25" in="SourceGraphic" in2="turbulence" />
    </filter>
    </defs>
    <text id="txt1" x="1%" y="50%"  >Stack</text>

</div>
```

- An example of animating image and text distortion

```css
.container {
width:75%;
height:75%;
}

#txt1 {
font-size: 100px;
font-weight:bold;
font-family: 'Signika', sans-serif;
fill:url(#rg);
filter:url(#myFilter);
pointer-events:none;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1"   viewBox="0 0 500 300">
  <defs> 
  <radialGradient id="rg" r=".9">
              <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#f00"></stop>
              <stop offset="10%" stop-color="#000"></stop>
              <stop offset="20%" stop-color="#f00"></stop>
              <stop offset="30%" stop-color="#000"></stop>
              <stop offset="40%" stop-color="#f00"></stop>
              <stop offset="50%" stop-color="#000"></stop>
              <stop offset="60%" stop-color="#f00"></stop>
              <stop offset="70%" stop-color="#000"></stop>
              <stop offset="80%" stop-color="#f00"></stop>
              <stop offset="90%" stop-color="#000"></stop>
              <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#f00"></stop>
            </radialGradient>
    <filter id="myFilter" >
      <feTurbulence type="turbulence" baseFrequency="0.0001" numOctaves="1" result="turbulence" >
     <animate attributeName="baseFrequency" dur="18s" values="0.0001;0.02;0.0001;0.02;0.0001" begin="img1.mouseover" end="img1.mouseout" />
      </feTurbulence>
    <feDisplacementMap xChannelSelector="R" yChannelSelector="G" scale="25" in="SourceGraphic" in2="turbulence" />
    </filter>
  </defs>
<image id="img1" xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/hHGO8.jpg" width="100%" height="100%" filter="url(#myFilter)" /> 
   <text id="txt1" x="35%" y="35%"  >Stack</text>
  </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! this is exactly what I was looking for :)

Comment: @rui Happy to help

Answer (score 3):

In order to make it work you will need to use a data uri for the `feImage`. I'm using your gradient but the filter you use has a way to small scale. I'm using `scale="15"`

```html
<svg width="300" height="300">
<defs>
<filter id="f" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x="0" y="0" width="300" height="300">
      <feImage xlink:href="data:image/svg+xml;utf8,%3Csvg width='300' height='300' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' xmlns:xlink='http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink'%3E%3Cdefs%3E %3CradialGradient id='rg' r='.7'%3E %3Cstop offset='0%25' stop-color='%23f00'%3E%3C/stop%3E%3Cstop offset='10%25' stop-color='%23000'%3E%3C/stop%3E%3Cstop offset='20%25' stop-color='%23f00'%3E%3C/stop%3E%3Cstop offset='30%25' stop-color='%23000'%3E%3C/stop%3E%3Cstop offset='40%25' stop-color='%23f00'%3E%3C/stop%3E%3Cstop offset='50%25' stop-color='%23000'%3E%3C/stop%3E%3Cstop offset='60%25' stop-color='%23f00'%3E%3C/stop%3E%3Cstop offset='70%25' stop-color='%23000'%3E%3C/stop%3E%3Cstop offset='80%25' stop-color='%23f00'%3E%3C/stop%3E%3Cstop offset='90%25' stop-color='%23000'%3E%3C/stop%3E%3Cstop offset='100%25' stop-color='%23f00'%3E%3C/stop%3E% %3C/radialGradient%3E%3C/defs%3E%3Crect fill='url(%23rg)' width='300' height='300'%3E%3C/rect%3E%3C/svg%3E" result="pict2"/>
      <feDisplacementMap scale="15" xChannelSelector="R" yChannelSelector="R" in2="pict2" in="SourceGraphic"/>
   </filter> 
</defs>
  
   <image xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/222579/beagle400.jpg" height="300" width="300" filter="url(#f)" />
</svg>
```

Also in your code you have several mistakes:
1. The `viewBox` attribute can't take units. This won't do: <del>viewBox="0,0,200vw,200vh"</del>
2. Also you can't do this: <del><text height="100vh"</del> or this: <del><tspan height="100vh"</del> however you can give your text a font-size.

Answer (score 0):

Speaking from my experience with Firefox, the only input allowed as `in2` in displacement map filter primitives is the output of the `feturbulence` element. So you'd have to create a gradient using `feturbulence` as a source. For a linear gradient going from left to right, from color *r1, g1, b1* to *r2, g2, b2* and filling the space from `0,0` to `100,100`, you'd have to create *xn* `feturbulence` outputs, where *xn* may be any number, but the larger it is, the smoother the gradient will be.
Every *n:th* `feturbulence` output, then have to have it's color channels altered using `fecolormatrix` as follows: `c = c1 * (1 - n/xn) + c2 * (n/xn)`, where *c* is the channel value, of the specific output, *c1* is the starting value of the channel, and *c2* is the ending value. And the height must be set to `100` for each element, and the width to `100/xn`, and the *x*-position to `n/xn*100`. Then use `femergenode` to bring all these outputs together into one output, that can then be used as `in2` in `fedisplacementmap`.